# Switching between P2d and WEBGL

Tags: javascript, webgl, p5.js

I have a p5.js sketch that uses simple drawings. I now want to add a 3D drawing, but WebGL will break the code I currently have.

Apart from having 2 canvases (one for P2D and one for WEBGL) is there a way to switch between the two rendering modes on the same canvas such that WEBGL doesn't break the code using P2D and P2D doesn't break the code using WEBGL?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error, I figured out a way to get around this. I used instance mode (a.k.a namespacing) and the show, hide and position method in p5.js

A video explaining namespacing well in p5.js:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su792jEauZg&t=1s

p5 reference for show:
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/show

p5 reference for hide:
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/hide

p5 reference for position:
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/position

sketch showing how show, hide and position is used:
https://editor.p5js.org/kan352/sketches/S1-b-Ij-l

This is the sample code i tried it on and it worked.

```
//webgl sketch
var canvas;

var webgl_sketch = function(w)
{
    w.setup = function()
    {
        w.canvas = w.createCanvas(600, 600, WEBGL);
        w.canvas.position(0,0);
        w.canvas.hide();
    
    }

    w.draw = function()
    {
        w.background(200);
        w.rotateX(w.frameCount * 0.01);
        w.rotateY(w.frameCount * 0.01);
        w.box(50);
    }
}

var three_Dim_sketch = new p5(webgl_sketch);


//p2d sketch
function setup()
{
    createCanvas(600, 600);
}


function draw()
{
    background(200);
    fill(0);
    ellipse(300, 300, 100);

    //displaying the webgl sketch when mouse X is > 300
    if(mouseX > 300)
        {
            three_Dim_sketch.canvas.show();
        }
    else if(mouseX < 300)
        {
            three_Dim_sketch.canvas.hide();
        }
}
```